# Meaning of the value true in myRequest.open("GET", url, true)?

Tags: html, xhtml

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
function loadXMLDoc(url)
{
myRequest.onreadystatechange = onResponse;
myRequest.open("GET", url, true);
myRequest.send();
}
function onResponse()
{
if(myRequest.readyState == 4 && myRequest.status == 200)
document.getElementById("A").innerHTML = myRequest.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("color")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Response: <span id="A"></span></p>
<button onclick="loadXMLDoc('example.xml')">Get Color</button>
</body>
</html>
```

a.meaning of the value true in myRequest.open("GET", url, true).

b. What values exists for the myRequest.readyState field, and what do they mean?

c. After the Get Color button is clicked, which portion of the example.htm code is updated?

d. If the XML file being accessed to get the color data has the following code:

```html
<color_list>
<color>Red</color>
<color>Green</color>
<color>Blue</color>
</color_list>
```

sketch the Web browser page display of the example.htm page after the Get Color button is pressed and the page is updated.